# Show filter attributes on non-category page with custom PHTML content that includes a product collection

Tags: magento2

I want to show specific products on a custom page. The products on the desired page are gathered with a custom attribute.

Now I want a category-page-like sidebar with filterable attributes, just like the normal category page has.

Or, simpler said: 
I want another category page, but not for a configured category but a custom attribute, including sidebar.

How do I achieve this?